# Stopping the use of a URL to get to the site

Tags: javascript, html, url

So I have a website which redirects to another part of the site ie, when pressing a button on "www.test.com" it reditects to "www.test.com/anotherpage". Now my problem is that I only want users to be able to access the second page when using the button and not just typing in "www.test.com/anotherpage" into the search bar.

So, is there any way to setup my page such that it cannot be accessed by the url but only redirected from another part of the website?

Comment: There are some easy ways that are easily bypassed, or some harder ways that take far more work to implement. What are you looking for, and what have you tried?

Comment: Another question would be do you have server side scripting ability?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you want to ensure that they login first, you should just have the second page check that they're logged in (check the session variable), rather than depend on where they came from.

Answer (score 0):

[document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

> The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access to the referring page.

Answer (score 0):

You need use Php code to login users and check sessions example like exaplain here: [Login form and session example](http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/) 
of course you need basic know about Php

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **client** or a **server** side technique.

Example of client side is Javascript, reading the [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) in the called page as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out, and redirecting to the home in case the referrer is not from your home page.

The server side way could make use of parameters passed to the page, like a [SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) identifier that will be generate on the home page, for example and checked in the called page.

Actually there are a different ways to accomplish your goal. 
You should provide some more info about the environment so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can usee PHP. Simply put your button between form tags

```
<form action="http://www.test.com/anotherpage" method="POST">
   <input name="mybutton" type="submit" value="Go to another page">
</form>
```

and on anotherpage

```
<?php 
 if (!isset($_POST['mybutton'])) { //check if the button was clicked
    header('Location: index.html'); //forward to index if not
 }
?>
```